# How to get the clearest text?

Tags: html, css

Below are four text samples from four browsers.

[image]

You can see how the 'e' and 's' are a bit ragged on Chrome and Safari.

How can I set up anti-aliasing, or whatever it takes, to make the text the clearest possible is all browsers?

Thanks

Comment: I would avoid using 'e's and 's's on my projects. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can antialise text in css for chrome like this:

```
body
{
   -webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
}
```

Here is the link you can read more: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/598

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see that this style made any difference in Chrome. If it's supposed to trigger a different font engine, it's as if something else is still disabling the switch, or the other font engine isn't there. The same thing goes for the two styles suggested by Suchan Lee below.

Answer (score 1):

Both Chrome and Safari use webkit for rendering. `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` will add antialias in webkit-based browsers and `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` improves text legibility in all browsers.

```
   body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      text-rendering: optimizeLegibility
   }
```